# Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection? Error..when i am trying load test a website which uses SSL

Tags: exception, jmeter

i am trying load test on website that uses SSL and https. I used badboy tool for recording and saved the script in .jmx . When i am trying to run the test it throws error:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext   connection?
at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.handleUnknownRecord(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(Unknown Source)
at   sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPJavaImpl.sample(HTTPJavaImpl.java:482)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy.sample(HTTPSamplerProxy.java:74)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1146)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1135)
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:465)
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:410)
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:241)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

and the http sampler setting is as below:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HXfX0.png)

I am new to Jmeter can any please solve my issue.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The error you're getting means that you are trying to establish secure (HTTPS) connection with the server which doesn't use any encryption and responds with the plain HTML.

I cannot reproduce your issue therefore I recommend recording your test scenario using one of the following approaches:

- [JMeter's HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.pdf)
- [JMeter Chrome Extension](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206732579-Chrome-Extension)